# How to remove marks left by robovac

Tags: flooring

I started using a robovac in my house, and today I noticed it leaving strange marks on the wood plank floor (see below).

[image]

I wanted to ask if anyone has any suggestions on how to fix these marks.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that was the robovac? They don’t usually have the mass or speed to mark like that. Has someone moved a table or chair and made that mark and you have only just noticed…

Comment: Yes .. I ran the robovac this afternoon .. and found the mark .. there are marks like this all over the house that weren't there this morning. I am using the Eufy 11S model.

Comment: @SolarMike Can this be called a scuff mark ? Because its the first time I have had this situation.

Comment: From your pic there seems to be an impression, which I would not use the word "scuff" for. All the robovacs I have seen, although I don't own one, have a soft rubber shell on the wheels - had it come off or been damaged?

Comment: The robovac was making a rattling noise. After it was done cleaning I popped out the front wheel and pushed it back in .. the noise then disappeared. The front wheel is just plastic. https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/NjYAAOSwB5tgSFXR/s-l400.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your last comment you have just answered the question.

As the front wheel was not correctly mounted, it was rolling on one edge.

This meant that the area the mass was concentrated on was smaller than designed which left marks in the floor surface.

Dealing with those marks may not be easy.

I have had success with real wood by adding moisture (wet rag) to the area and the wood swells back up. But not too much water and it takes time and care. If that is not real wood then you might not have an easy solution except to move the affected pieces to out-of-the-way places.

Comment: Gentle application is called for! However, if a damp rag/washcloth doesn't do the trick, a **gentle** application of heat to make steam may do the trick. If you have a clothing steamer, try that. Otherwise, a heat gun aimed at a damp rag or _cringe_ an iron, may help pull the mark out. **WARNING** you could end up doing _more_ damage by applying heat than you already have - weigh this possibility against your desire to pull these dents.